# allow only urls that have a parameter in

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, parameter-passing, url-parameters

so, I have a `url` that redirects to another doing a `Double Meta Refresh (cleans referer)` and I would like to only allow to see the `second url` when the `url comes with a parameter`.

**the current setup is:**

```
urlA.php  --DMR--->  urlB.php
```

I want to users to be able to see `urlB only if they come from urlA`, but as the referrer is cleaned in the middle I don't think I can check via referrer in `.htacces` for example.

so I was thinking on checking on a parameter, so urlB is only accessible when a special parameter comes, something like:

```
urlA.php  ----DMR--->  urlB.php   ///NOT POSSIBLE

urlA.php?key=xxxx  ----DMR--->  urlB.php   /// POSSIBLE
```

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surely if you are passing a GET parameter you can use:

```
<?php 
if(!isset($_GET["key"]) || $_GET["key"] !== "urlA.php"){
   die("you must come from a certain page" );
}else{
  echo "You came from the right place";
}
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error:

Fatal error: Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead) in /home/XXX/test.php on line 4

Comment: that made it work, but would you be able to please rephrase it so it "dies" if the key is not the exact key?  (this is because I have a lot of html content that I want to load only if the key is correct.

Comment: The triple === will make sure it is the correct key, please provide an example that doesn't match that, you will need to change "urlA.php" to what ever parameter you are passing :)

Comment: For example if you have "key=xxxx" you will need to change the code to if(isset($_GET["key"]) && $_GET["key"] === "xxxx"){

Comment: yes, I understood that,
but I was thinking something like

if key (different from) XXX then
DIE
else
continue


I know I'm horrible expressing it :P

Comment: Ive switched it around for you, but im not aware that it would make any difference to code execution time,  please accept the answer if this is correct.